# Solving a system of ODEs using ODE45

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

I am trying to learn how to use MATLAB to solve a system of differential equations (Lorenz equations) and plot each solution as a function of t

```
X’ = −σx + σy  
Y’ = ρx − y − xz
Z’ = −βz + xy
```

where `σ = 10`, `β = 8/3`, and `ρ = 28`, as well as `x(0) = −8`, `y(0) = 8`, and `z(0) = 27`.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
function xprime = example(t,x)

sig    = 10;
beta   = 8/3;
rho    = 28;
xprime = [-sig*x(1) + sig*x(2); 
           rho*x(1) - x(2) - x(1)*x(3); 
          -beta*x(3) + x(1)*x(2)];

x0    = [-8 8 27]; 
tspan = [0 20]; 
[t,x] = ode45(@example, tspan, x0);

figure 
plot(t,x(:,1)), hold on
plot(t,x(:,2)), hold on
plot(t,x(:,3)), hold off
```

However, this generates an error, how do I fix this? I am not sure what input arguments are missing or where I am going wrong. I appreciate any help, thanks.

> Not enough input arguments.
>
> Error in example (line 9)
>      xprime=[-sig*x(1) + sig*x(2); rho*x(1) - x(2) - x(1)*x(3); -beta*x(3) +
>      x(1)*x(2)];

Comment: You are recursing -- is that intentional, or...?

Comment: Perhaps, I am but that's only because I do not know of a better way to write it.

Answer (score 3):

That is actually a pretty good first try!

The problem is that when you press the <kbd>Run</kbd> button (or press F5),  you're calling the function `example` with no arguments; which is what MATLAB is complaining about.

A second problem is that, even if you were to be able to run the function like this, `ode45` would call the function `example`, which would call `ode45`, which would call `example`, which would call `ode45` and so on, until the recursion limit is reached.

The solution to both is to split it up in two functions (these may be written into the same M-file):

```
% top-level function; no arguments
function caller() 

    x0    = [-8 8 27]; 
    tspan = [0 20]; 
    [t,x] = ode45(@example, tspan, x0);

    figure 
    plot(t,x(:,1)), hold on
    plot(t,x(:,2)), hold on
    plot(t,x(:,3)), hold off

end

% The derivative 
function xprime = example(t,x)

    sig    = 10;
    beta   = 8/3;
    rho    = 28;
    xprime = [-sig*x(1) + sig*x(2); 
               rho*x(1) - x(2) - x(1)*x(3); 
              -beta*x(3) + x(1)*x(2)];              
end
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining, this helps.